# pandas multiply other columns by another

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a scaling factor on some data:

```
col1   col2   col3

10      4      5
100     2      3
1000    6      7
```

Then, i would like the output to be:

```
col1   col2   col3

10      40       50
100     200      300
1000    6000     7000
```

I was trying to use a lambda but it kept throwing me errors.

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.mul` with `axis=0`

When Pandas operates between a `DataFrame` and a `Series` it aligns the index of the `Series` with the columns of the `DataFrame`.  We can alter that behavior by utilizing the equivalent operation method and passing the `axis=0` argument to tell Pandas to align the `Series` index with the `DataFrame` index.

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df[['col2', 'col3']].mul(df['col1'], axis=0)
df

   col1  col2  col3
0    10    40    50
1   100   200   300
2  1000  6000  7000
```

A shorter way of doing this

```
df.update(df.drop('col1', 1).mul(df.col1, axis=0))
```

---

#### in-line

And not **in-place**.  Meaning, produce a copy and leave the original alone

```
df.assign(**df.drop('col1', 1).mul(df.col1, axis=0))

   col1  col2  col3
0    10    40    50
1   100   200   300
2  1000  6000  7000
```

---

#### After thought

I was messing around with this completely hacky way of doing it.

```
[df.get(c).__imul__(df.col1) for c in [*df][1:]];
```

Super gross as it depends on a side effect of the comprehension and throws the result of the comprehension away.

Please ignore this!